# Class in a class in Godot, how do you access things from the containing class?

Tags: godot, godot-4

I have a class inside a class.  I would like the inner class to be able to access functions from the outer class.  Something like what's below:

```
@onready var my_label = $MarginContainer/Panel/Label

func display_text(text: String):
    my_label.set_text(text)
    
class DialogueSession
    var num = 1
    func show_next():
         display_text("the next number is:" + num++)
```

I get the error:

> Error: Function display_text() not found in base self

How can I achieve this code structuring?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass `self` into the `DialogueSession._init()`, like so:

```
@onready var my_label = $MarginContainer/Panel/Label

func display_text(text: String):
    my_label.set_text(text)

func create_dialogue_session():
    return DialogueSession.new(self)

class DialogueSession:
    var container_class
    _init(c_c):
        container_class = c_c

    func show_next():
         container_class.display_text("the next number is:" + num++)
```

I do not believe this is likely to be the best way